# Phonegap height change in IOS?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, objective-c, cordova

I have a simple phonegap project, i want to add admob to it, i need to decrees the phonegap height to leave a 50dp space in the top of the screen, and leave 90dp when on ipad, im not sure about the way to do this, right now i just left a 50dp space in the html file where i place admob to the top of the screen above that html, im sure this is not the right way if i want to use smart banners for Iphones and ipads.

i trying doing some changes with this code but with no luck, im sure there is another way.

```
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];

self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:screenBounds] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to get and update the webView frame.  Something like below that also support screen rotation:

```
// detect orientation 
UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];
BOOL isLandScape = (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(currentOrientation));

CGRect webViewFrame = webView.frame;
CGRect superViewFrame = webView.superview.frame;
CGRect bannerViewFrame = bannerView.frame;

// Frame of the main Cordova webview and its max size
CGFloat webViewHeight = superViewFrame.size.height;

// define height for banner, 0 if hidden
CGFloat bannerHeight = bannerViewFrame.size.height;

if (bannerView.hidden){
  bannerHeight = 0.0;
}

// set different size for landscape
if (isLandScape) {
  webViewHeight = superViewFrame.size.width;
}

webViewHeight -= bannerHeight;
webViewFrame.size.height = webViewHeight;

// move webview x location
webViewFrame.origin.x = bannerHeight;

// finally set the frame
webView.frame = webViewFrame;
```